# Calling Craft API from node.js

Tags: structure, plugin-elementapi

I really love working with Craft, especially around how easy and user friendly it is. However, I do work with React/Vue and usually I setup a node server/app that will do some routing, render views and so on...

Would it be a good idea to have a setup like this:

- Frontend: React / Vue
- Backend: node app that has all my public routes setup, rendering views, server side render React/Vue etc
- Backend no 2: Craft CMS with Element API setup

Example:

- User requests /contact/person-1
- The request will be matched in my node app as a valid route
- Node app will make request to the API that has been setup for Craft, fetches the relevant info about Person 1, returns the result to node
- Node app renders the view with the data that was fetched

Is this O.K. or completely nuts? Will it be ineffective or is it a good way to structure it like this when I'm in need for a nice CMS like Craft... ?

Please help me out on finding the best approach!

Comment: @nicklman I like to know what is the conclusion of this? did you able to work with React, Node Craft and EAPI?

Comment: Yes. I did it like I describe in my list. In order to get SSR to work, and do the necessary requests before view is rendered I used frontload-connect in my React setup. But if a user navigates to another route after the first route he/she entered, the api request will happen on frontend only, but thats more of how React Router works = it renders the requested route right away. In those cases I just put up a spinner while fetching api data. Does that answer some of your questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can definitely do this... the article [Using VueJS + GraphQL to make Practical Magic](https://nystudio107.com/blog/using-vuejs-graphql-to-make-practical-magic) has a detailed explanation of how to accomplish this using the CraftQL plugin and GraphQL... which I think you may find much nicer to work with than custom Element API endpoint(s).

However you can definitely do it with an Element API endpoint as well. It's just a bit more work, and a bit more in PHP-land.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using craft in 'headless' mode. I've heard about that for drupal, but not for craft. I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work. You get the craft UX for creating and modifying entities, but use node as a proxy and view generator.

Comment: Yes, exactly, looks like it could be a nice way to go then. Cheers